# Resolve the error is unfortunately has stopped?

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my first program on android studio 
it is just hello word sample but there is a problem 
When I offer on a simulated This message appears "unfortunately My app has stopped"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7livY.png)
please  help me 
some lines from the logcat is :

```
07-31 13:29:51.031      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 58K, 10% free 2243K/2492K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 91ms
    07-31 13:29:51.041      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f4 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_on_disabled_holo_light) that varies with 
    07-31 13:29:52.421      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ed (android:drawable/btn_toggle_off_normal_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:52.482      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e7 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_off_disabled_focused_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:52.511      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e9 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_off_disabled_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:52.581      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e9 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_off_disabled_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:52.681      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 147K, 10% free 2247K/2492K, paused 1ms+23ms, total 102ms
    07-31 13:29:52.771      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f7 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_on_normal_holo_dark) that varies with #0x10801f5 (android:drawable/btn_toggle_on_focused_holo_dark) that varies with 
    07-31 13:29:53.732      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805e6 (android:drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_holo_light) that varies 
    07-31 13:29:53.910      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805e2 (android:drawable/textfield_multiline_default_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:53.941      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805e4 (android:drawable/textfield_multiline_disabled_focused_holo_light) that 
    07-31 13:29:54.031      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805d5 (android:drawable/textfield_default_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!

    07-31 13:29:54.221      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805d8 (android:drawable/textfield_disabled_focused_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:29:54.221      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805da (android:drawable/textfield_disabled_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!

    07-31 13:30:00.311    1548-1548/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    07-31 13:30:00.391    1562-1562/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:00.391    1562-1562/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:00.412      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080496 (android:drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo8) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.412      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080496 (android:drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo8) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.451    1548-1548/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    07-31 13:30:00.451    1548-1552/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 89K, 17% free 445K/536K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
    07-31 13:30:00.481    1548-1554/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    07-31 13:30:00.541      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 720K, 28% free 2263K/3116K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 127ms
    07-31 13:30:00.582    1562-1562/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:00.582    1562-1562/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:00.611      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f9 (android:drawable/spinner_76_outer_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.611      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f8 (android:drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.611      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f8 (android:drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.693      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 110K, 28% free 2260K/3116K, paused 53ms+23ms, total 85ms
    07-31 13:30:00.851      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f7 (android:drawable/spinner_48_outer_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.880      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f6 (android:drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.880      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f6 (android:drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:00.991      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080484 (android:drawable/progress_primary_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.132      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 50K, 28% free 2260K/3116K, paused 1ms+81ms, total 140ms
    07-31 13:30:01.171      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080485 (android:drawable/progress_primary_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.211      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080486 (android:drawable/progress_secondary_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.241      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080487 (android:drawable/progress_secondary_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.311      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f3 (android:drawable/spinner_16_outer_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.371      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f2 (android:drawable/spinner_16_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.371      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804f2 (android:drawable/spinner_16_inner_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.451      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e3 (android:drawable/scrubber_track_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.561      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e2 (android:drawable/scrubber_secondary_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.591    1574-1574/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    07-31 13:30:01.591    1574-1574/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
    07-31 13:30:01.601      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804df (android:drawable/scrubber_primary_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.601      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e3 (android:drawable/scrubber_track_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.691      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e4 (android:drawable/scrubber_track_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.731      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e2 (android:drawable/scrubber_secondary_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.761      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804df (android:drawable/scrubber_primary_holo) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.761      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e4 (android:drawable/scrubber_track_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:01.831    1574-1574/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:01.831    1574-1574/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:01.951      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d6 (android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.012      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d7 (android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_holo_light) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.071    1574-1574/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:02.071    1574-1574/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    07-31 13:30:02.121      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x108050c (android:drawable/spinner_disabled_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.161      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080514 (android:drawable/spinner_pressed_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.211      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080510 (android:drawable/spinner_focused_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.251      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x108050a (android:drawable/spinner_default_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.251      795-795/? W/Resources﹕ Preloaded drawable resource #0x108050a (android:drawable/spinner_default_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!
    07-31 13:30:02.371      795-795/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 28% free 2271K/3116K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 38ms
    07-31 13:30:29.281    1648-1689/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
    07-31 13:30:29.281    1648-1689/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
    07-31 13:30:29.281    1648-1689/system_process D/EventHub﹕ No input device configuration file found for device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'.
    07-31 13:30:29.281    1648-1689/system_process I/EventHub﹕ New device: id=2, fd=88, path='/dev/input/event1', name='AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', classes=0x3, configuration='', keyLayout='/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl', keyCharacterMap='/system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm', builtinKeyboard=false, usingSuspendBlockIoctl=false, usingClockIoctl=false
    07-31 13:30:29.302    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Device added: id=-1, name='Virtual', sources=0x00000301
    07-31 13:30:29.302    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Device added: id=2, name='AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', sources=0x00000101
    07-31 13:30:29.302    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Touch device 'qwerty2' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
    07-31 13:30:29.302    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Device added: id=0, name='qwerty2', sources=0x00001103
    07-31 13:30:29.302    1648-1689/system_process E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    07-31 13:30:29.342    1648-1671/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Couldn't create dir.: /data/system/inputmethod
    07-31 13:30:29.482    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Accessibility Manager
    07-31 13:30:29.501    1648-1671/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to write /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/adj
    07-31 13:30:29.501    1648-1671/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to write /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree
    07-31 13:30:29.501    1648-1671/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Config changes=15f8 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h508dp 240dpi nrml long port ?uimode ?night finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.2}
    07-31 13:30:29.501    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
    07-31 13:30:29.501    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 480x800, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
    07-31 13:30:29.542    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Mount Service
    07-31 13:30:29.552    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
    07-31 13:30:29.552    1648-1689/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 480x800, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
    07-31 13:30:29.572    1648-1671/system_process D/MountService﹕ got storage path: /mnt/sdcard description: USB storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: false maxFileSize: 0
    07-31 13:30:29.572    1648-1671/system_process D/MountService﹕ addVolumeLocked() StorageVolume [mStorageId=0 mPath=/mnt/sdcard mDescriptionId=17040615 mPrimary=true mRemovable=false mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 mAllowMassStorage=false mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null]
    07-31 13:30:29.592    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ LockSettingsService
    07-31 13:30:29.642    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Device Policy
    07-31 13:30:29.652    1648-1693/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GREF has increased to 201
    07-31 13:30:29.662    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Status Bar
    07-31 13:30:29.672    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Clipboard Service
    07-31 13:30:29.682    1648-1693/system_process D/MountService﹕ volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (null -> unmounted)
    07-31 13:30:29.682    1648-1693/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Updating external media status from unmounted to unmounted
    07-31 13:30:29.702    1648-1693/system_process W/MountService﹕ getSecureContainerList() called when storage not mounted
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ No secure containers on sdcard
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
    07-31 13:30:29.712    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
    07-31 13:30:29.722    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
    07-31 13:30:29.722    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x89be45)
    07-31 13:30:29.722    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
    07-31 13:30:29.722    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
    07-31 13:30:29.752    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ NetworkManagement Service
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER in package com.android.exchange
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER in package com.android.email
    07-31 13:30:29.762    1648-1693/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x88be45)
    07-31 13:30:29.862    1648-1649/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 9% free 3900K/4252K, paused 8ms+1ms, total 26ms
    07-31 13:30:29.882    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Text Service Manager Service
    07-31 13:30:29.992    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ NetworkStats Service
    07-31 13:30:30.042    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ NetworkPolicy Service
    07-31 13:30:30.062    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Wi-Fi P2pService
    07-31 13:30:30.122    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Wi-Fi Service
    07-31 13:30:30.222     791-1212/? E/CommandListener﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
    07-31 13:30:30.272    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Connectivity Service
    07-31 13:30:30.282    1648-1699/system_process E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1 interface ipv6 wlan0 disable' failed with '400 1 Failed to change IPv6 state (No such file or directory)'
    07-31 13:30:30.292    1648-1671/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ ConnectivityService starting up
    07-31 13:30:30.402    1648-1671/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
    07-31 13:30:30.402    1648-1671/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: Could not enable APN type "default"
    07-31 13:30:30.472    1648-1671/system_process I/WifiService﹕ WifiService starting up with Wi-Fi disabled
    07-31 13:30:30.492    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Network Service Discovery Service
    07-31 13:30:30.542    1648-1671/system_process D/NsdService﹕ Network service discovery enabled true
    07-31 13:30:30.552    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Throttle Service
    07-31 13:30:30.562    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ UpdateLock Service
    07-31 13:30:30.662    1648-1649/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 240K, 8% free 4044K/4368K, paused 5ms+10ms, total 25ms
    07-31 13:30:30.752    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Notification Manager
    07-31 13:30:30.762    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Device Storage Monitor
    07-31 13:30:30.811    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Location Manager
    07-31 13:30:30.822    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Country Detector
    07-31 13:30:30.822    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Search Service
    07-31 13:30:30.832    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ DropBox Service
    07-31 13:30:30.842    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Wallpaper Service
    07-31 13:30:30.872    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Audio Service
    07-31 13:30:31.472    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Dock Observer
    07-31 13:30:31.472    1648-1671/system_process W/DockObserver﹕ This kernel does not have dock station support
    07-31 13:30:31.472    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Wired Accessory Manager
    07-31 13:30:31.482    1648-1671/system_process W/WiredAccessoryManager﹕ This kernel does not have wired headset support
    07-31 13:30:31.482    1648-1671/system_process W/WiredAccessoryManager﹕ This kernel does not have usb audio support
    07-31 13:30:31.482    1648-1671/system_process W/WiredAccessoryManager﹕ This kernel does not have HDMI audio support
    07-31 13:30:31.482    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ USB Service
    07-31 13:30:31.542    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Serial Service
    07-31 13:30:31.552    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Twilight Service
    07-31 13:30:31.552    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ UI Mode Manager Service
    07-31 13:30:31.572    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Backup Service
    07-31 13:30:31.642    1648-1671/system_process V/BackupManagerService﹕ No ancestral data
    07-31 13:30:31.832    1648-1649/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 211K, 7% free 4328K/4616K, paused 18ms+29ms, total 171ms
    07-31 13:30:31.902    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ Found stale backup journal, scheduling
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ android
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.browser
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.calendar
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.inputmethod.latin
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.providers.settings
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.providers.userdictionary
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ com.android.sharedstoragebackup
    07-31 13:30:31.912    1648-1671/system_process I/BackupManagerService﹕ Backup enabled => true
    07-31 13:30:31.922    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ AppWidget Service
    07-31 13:30:31.932    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Recognition Service
    07-31 13:30:31.932    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ DiskStats Service
    07-31 13:30:31.932    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ SamplingProfiler Service
    07-31 13:30:31.982    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ NetworkTimeUpdateService
    07-31 13:30:31.992    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ CommonTimeManagementService
    07-31 13:30:31.992    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ CertBlacklister
    07-31 13:30:32.002    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Dreams Service
    07-31 13:30:32.012    1648-1671/system_process I/WindowManager﹕ SAFE MODE not enabled
    07-31 13:30:32.461    1648-1671/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ System now ready
    07-31 13:30:32.522    1648-1671/system_process I/SystemServer﹕ Making services ready
    07-31 13:30:32.612    1648-1671/system_process I/Zygote﹕ Process: zygote socket opened
    07-31 13:30:32.682    1648-1671/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.android.systemui for service com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService: pid=1715 uid=10034 gids={50034, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001}
    07-31 13:30:32.701    1648-1671/system_process D/NetworkManagementService﹕ not enabling bandwidth control
    07-31 13:30:32.732      789-845/? I/Vold﹕ /dev/block/vold/179:0 being considered for volume sdcard
    07-31 13:30:32.732      789-845/? D/Vold﹕ Volume sdcard state changing 1 (Idle-Unmounted) -> 3 (Checking)
    07-31 13:30:32.742      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ ** /dev/block/vold/179:0
    07-31 13:30:32.762      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ ** Phase 1 - Read and Compare FATs
    07-31 13:30:32.762      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ Attempting to allocate 2044 KB for FAT
    07-31 13:30:32.792    1648-1692/system_process D/MountService﹕ volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (unmounted -> checking)
    07-31 13:30:32.792    1648-1692/system_process D/MountService﹕ sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING dat=file:///mnt/sdcard (has extras) } to UserHandle{-1}
    07-31 13:30:32.792      799-799/? I/keystore﹕ uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
    07-31 13:30:32.922     791-1212/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -F fw_INPUT
    07-31 13:30:33.222      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ Attempting to allocate 2044 KB for FAT
    07-31 13:30:33.572     791-1212/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -F fw_OUTPUT
    07-31 13:30:33.652     791-1212/? E/Netd﹕ exec() res=768 for /system/bin/ip6tables -F fw_FORWARD
    07-31 13:30:33.671    1648-1671/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {2 firewall disable} took too long (841ms)
    07-31 13:30:33.722      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ ** Phase 2 - Check Cluster Chains
    07-31 13:30:33.751      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ ** Phase 3 - Checking Directories
    07-31 13:30:33.751      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ ** Phase 4 - Checking for Lost Files
    07-31 13:30:33.762      789-845/? I//system/bin/fsck_msdos﹕ 12 files, 1044448 free (522224 clusters)
    07-31 13:30:33.782      789-845/? I/Vold﹕ Filesystem check completed OK
    07-31 13:30:33.782      789-845/? I/Vold﹕ Device /dev/block/vold/179:0, target /mnt/sdcard mounted @ /mnt/secure/staging
    07-31 13:30:33.782      789-845/? D/Vold﹕ Volume sdcard state changing 3 (Checking) -> 4 (Mounted)
    07-31 13:30:33.792    1648-1692/system_process D/MountService﹕ volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (checking -> mounted)
    07-31 13:30:33.792    1648-1692/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Updating external media status from unmounted to mounted
    07-31 13:30:33.792    1648-1690/system_process E/VoldConnector﹕ NDC Command {3 volume mount /mnt/sdcard} took too long (1107ms)
    07-31 13:30:33.802    1648-1671/system_process W/SystemServer﹕ ***********************************************
    07-31 13:30:33.842    1648-1692/system_process D/MountService﹕ sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///mnt/sdcard (has extras) } to UserHandle{-1}
    07-31 13:30:34.012    1648-1671/system_process A/SystemServer﹕ BOOT FAILURE making Network Managment Service ready
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '2 firewall disable' failed with '400 2 Firewall command failed'
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.setFirewallEnabled(NetworkManagementService.java:1446)
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.prepareNativeDaemon(NetworkManagementService.java:376)
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.systemReady(NetworkManagementService.java:213)
                at com.android.server.ServerThread$3.run(SystemServer.java:882)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:7880)
                at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:866)
         Caused by: com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector$NativeDaemonFailureException: command '2 firewall disable' failed with '400 2 Firewall command failed'
                at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:349)
                at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.executeForList(NativeDaemonConnector.java:286)
                at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.execute(NativeDaemonConnector.java:252)
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.setFirewallEnabled(NetworkManagementService.java:1443)
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.prepareNativeDaemon(NetworkManagementService.java:376)
                at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.systemReady(NetworkManagementService.java:213)
                at com.android.server.ServerThread$3.run(SystemServer.java:882)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.systemReady(ActivityManagerService.java:7880)
                at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:866)
    07-31 13:30:34.022    1648-1677/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ No secure containers on sdcard
```

Comment: Try with a different emulator

Comment: That image and error message are pointless to add.. Any app that crashes says that. Please [edit] your question to better format the logcat

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now, there is nothing evident about your app in these logs and the only exception says something about a firewall.

Comment: Can you please try to "clear the logcat (using the recycle bin on the right), and let the app crash again." -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: thanks Shaishav  < 
i tried with a different emulator without any results